# Android: Add a ViewmodelFactory to a viewModel by NavGaphViewmodels

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm learning Kotlin and I have a viewModel which is created as navGraphViewModels().

```
private val viewModel: CreationSignalementViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.creation_signalement_nav_graph)
```

I would like to know if it's possible to add a ViewModelFactory to this viewModel declaration ?

thank you :)

Comment: `private val viewModel: CreationSignalementViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.creation_signalement_nav_graph) { myViewModelFactory }`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it !